# Image resizing gone wonky

Tags: support, images

In [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries) the revised version shows (at least for me, in FF) the pics and captions no longer lining up here:

[image]

... and here:

[image]

as an additional "funny", if I click on the top left picture "The Whole Plant", *intending to enlarge it* it actually pops up a smaller version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, it did break on FF and I fixed it now. It looks fine on FF and Safari and Chrome. Normally I give a little bit of wiggle room for the images, but this time I made it a little too much of a tight fit, and that might've pushed it to the next line in FF. Sorry about that and please let me know if it looks OK to you now.

I resize images and organize them neatly (or try to) a lot on this site, primarily because images are extremely important on Gardening, perhaps more so than most other sites. I for one, am easily impressed by a rival gardening website when they have neatly formatted text and pretty, orderly figures. I don't care so much for neatness and order when I'm looking at websites related to my day-to-day work. I guess that just comes with the nature of the topic.

So it's mostly been a personal mission to improve the appearance of the site, and I see Mike Perry has joined me in this of late, which is encouraging. Normally, people just post a whole bunch of high-res images, which makes scrolling very hard. I don't know about others, but by the time I scroll down to the last picture, I've half forgotten what the question was about. It's the same as the "forum effect" where scrolling down to an answer is blocked by either too much info or irrelevant info.

I think a neat display of images instead of a big list certainly helps boost the appearance  of the question. But if others think that this is utterly irrelevant or if it is detrimental, please let me know and I'll stop.

Comment: only detrimental when and if broken a little bit (as in my screenshot). but fixed now, thanks for looking at it so carefully.

Comment: Well, I try my best not to break images, but I can't keep tabs on all browsers and versions out there. You certainly could've edited to fix it, y'know ;)

Comment: @yoda Any update on, if, SE Gardening will get some much needed updated functionality to its image handling capabilities? As you know, I totally agree with you on how important images are here on SE Gardening...

Comment: That thumbnails are needed is not in question. An easy way to directly insert pictures as thumbnails into a post is what is needed most!